# Node js server not taking the updated file

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-loader

I am running the node js application. In package.json I am building the file like below and running with the start command from package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "build:server": "npx babel server --out-dir dist/server",
    "start": "node ./dist/server/app.js",
    "build:client": "webpack"
  }
```

When I execute the build command, the changes were available in the dist folder. But I run the start command I am not able to see my changes on executing my Rest API call.

Comment: Did you run the start command _after_ executing the build command?

Comment: Yes. But not working